# Bound for a character sum

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

We know that Weil's bound tells
$$\left| \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_{q}} \chi(f(x))  \right| \leq (d-1)\sqrt{q},$$
where $\chi$ is a multiplicative character of order $m$, $f$ is not an $m$th power in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$, and $d$ counts the number of distinct roots of $f$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$.

I am curious about the following sum
$$\left| \sum_{x_1 \in \mathbb{F}_{q}}\cdots \sum_{x_n \in \mathbb{F}_{q}} \chi(f(x_1,\ldots,x_n))  \right|,$$
where again $\chi$ is a multiplicative character of order $m$ and $f$ is not an $m$th power in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Could anyone give me some references on the bound of this sum?

Comment: I'm afraid I need to search my books about the second sum as I rarely needed those back in the day. A trivial corollary of Weil bound has order $\mathcal{O}(q^{n-1/2})$, but IIRC there are seriously better bounds due to Deligne for some special cases. The trivial bound is achieved for some types of polynomials. For example, when $f$ really only depends on a single variable you will get $q^{n-1}$ copies of the single variable sum.

Comment: Similarly, if $\chi$ has order two, and
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1^2+1)x_2^2x_3^2\cdots x_n^2.$$ The factors not depending on $x_1$ "don't do anything", and we get sums like $q^{n-{1/2}}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, it should be $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$. Thank you for the correction. I also noticed that the Weil bound may deduce the trivial bound you mentioned. Btw, is there a positive density of polynomials achieving this trivial bound? Or density zero?